# Handling .dll not in GAC moving between DEBUG and Release

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Ok, I have had a good look and found nothing useful on this problem.
I have a solution in VS (Visual Studio). It has two projects say ProjectA and ProjectB.

ProjectA creates `A.dll`. 
ProjectB creates `B.EXE` which references `A.dll`.

In DEBUG mode everything works correctly as you would expect. However, in release mode the files are moved to where they will be located when installed. The `A.dll` will not be installed in the GAC. Because the `A.dll` is not where it is expected to be in relation to `B.EXE` the exes fail. Reasonable enough.

In the After Build Event I copy the .exes to `c:\los\` and `A.dll` gets moved to `c:\los\libs\`

Currently I have to de-reference the `A.dll` and then re-reference it now pointing it to it's new location, rebuild and then the release version works. The real solution has a lot of projects and a great number of .dlls which means I can easily (and do) forget to re-reference new .dlls regularly.

**Is there a way to automate this tiresome process?**

Comment: Why are you not using GAC

Comment: It is a requirement.

Comment: does changing the configuration in build properties to all configuration help?
rather than having different configurations for debug and release.

Comment: What type is ProjectA? Console? Library? I am asking because I didn't encounter project that its build result with exe and dll. Maybe you mean SolutionA?

Comment: @KernelMode You are right - sorry trying to simplify and ended up making a mistake.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Unfortunately that will not solve the problem.

Comment: So in release mode, A.dll is in a subfolder from where B.exe is located. How are the folder relationships in debug mode? Same folder?

Comment: @Christoph In DEBUG mode the folder structure is solution folder, ProjectA folder, ProjectB folder, then obviously in the project folders you have the Bin\Debug and Bin\Release folders.

So Solution\ProjectA\Bin\Debug and Solution\ProjectB\Bin\Debug

Comment: I meant, when both projects are built and you execute B.exe, where A.dll located in relation to A.dll? Typically, VS copies a referenced DLL into the output folder of the referencing project. So I suspect that A.dll and B.exe are in the same folder when you execute your debug build.

Comment: @Christoph the "relative" locations of the files are very different between the debug and release builds.

Comment: "in release mode the files are moved to where they will be located when installed". Who installs your app? If you don't have control of how the files will be distributed in Release how did you manage to put all under c:\los?

Comment: @KernelMode it is a requirement demanded by the business. We have full control over the release and installation.

Comment: How did you define that in production some files will be under c:\los and other under c:\los\libs\? Post build event is not enough. You need to have control (or some knowledge) on your installer.

Comment: @KernelMode It is our own custom installer.
Still trying the probing... does not seem to be working - may have to change the references somehow in B.EXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the probing feature of .Net. Here is the reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx

Example:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="libs"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Probing has the limitation that only subfolders can be searched from where the executing EXE is running. However, since your EXE is in C:\Ios and the DLL is in the subfolder C:\Ios\Libs. Per the documentation you can specify multiple subfolders. I just put the "Libs" folder into the example to match your question.

Comment: Having a look now.